# Post Request Required Error Solspace Freeform

Tags: craft3, form, plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

I installed Solspace Freeform onto a new site and am getting this error on form submission.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix.  The error was being caused by wrapping the freeform render in  tags.  Removing these changed the request type and now it works.

Ex: It should be:

```
 {{ craft.freeform.form("contactForm").render() }}
```

and not

```
<form>
  {{ craft.freeform.form("contactForm").render() }}
</form>
```